# PostgreSQL : Backup Database using Python pg_dump error

Tags: python, postgresql

i have this code

```
tables = ['order','transaction','user']

for table_name in tables:
    path_backup = folder_backup + "/" + table_name + "_table_backup.sql"
    try:
        os.environ["PGPASSWORD"] = PASSWORD
        command = """pg_dump -v --inserts -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres testing -n public -t table_name > path_backup"""
        os.system(command)
        print("ok")
    except:
        print("error")
```

sometimes this error happen

```
pg_dump: error: Error message from server: ERROR:  canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
DETAIL:  User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed.
```

my question is how to retry the pg_dump on the same table if the error occured?

Comment: Have you tried to put a loop around the try/except?

Comment: like this?

while os.command(command) != 0:
   os.command(command)

Comment: Do you want to run the command twice for every error? If not, you should save the exit code to a variable

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: `code = os.command(command); while code!=0: code = os.command(command)`